# Cypress gets stuck in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress, jenkins-cli

I have a problem with Jenkins and Cypress. I'm using the docker to run my specs inside it and it gets stuck at this step: `cypress:cli piping child STDERR to process STDERR`

What should I do? Locally is working as expected. Thank you!

This is how it looks a part of my script, after cloning project.

```
stage('Test') {
        docker.image("cypress/included:4.11.0").inside('-e "HOME=." -e "npm_config_cache=npm-cache" --entrypoint=""'){ c ->
            sh 'npm i'
            // sh 'npm run tests-headless'
            sh 'DEBUG=cypress:* cypress run --browser chrome --headless'
        }            
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: @CarlosNasser nope. reported also to Cypress and nothing.

Comment: thanks, I let you know if find a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a way to make it work. You need to run the docker container as root.

```
withDockerContainer(args: '--cpus="1.0" --entrypoint="" -e DEBUG=cypress:* -u root', image:'cypress/included:5.0.0') {
     //Your code
}
```

Comment: Tried to run with ".inside('-e "HOME=." -e "npm_config_cache=npm-cache" --entrypoint="" -u root')" and it didn't fix. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is ".inside()" equivalent to my args? I am not sure if that is injecting the args for the docker run.

Comment: Yes, is acting like args. I didn't find a way to fix this.